# Set Standard Objects as Menu Item in Salesforce1?

Tags: salesforce1-app

I have a request to set standard objects as part of the Menu Items (highlighted in red below) in Salesforce1. Is this possible and how can I do it?

[image]

Comment: I ran into this problem and had to search for a bit because I simply couldn't believe they wouldn't allow you to do this. However, it isn't currently supported so I figured I would share.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, with the current release of Salesforce1, this is not possible. From the [Salesforce1 Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.186.0.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/customize_s1_nav_about.htm):

> **About the Salesforce1 Navigation Menu**
>
> Anywhere your users see the Salesforce1 App Nav icon in Salesforce1, they can tap it to access the
>   menu. As an administrator, you can customize what the menu contains.
>
> **What You Can Include**
>
> Depending on how your organization is configured and what they have access to, your users could see multiple
>   items in their navigation menu.
>
> - Dashboards—Availability depends on edition and user permissions.
> - Feed—Displays for organizations that have Chatter enabled.
> - Flexible Pages—Custom Salesforce1 app home pages. For more information, see [What is a Flexible Page?](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.186.0.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/flexipages_whatis.htm) in the Salesforce1 App Developer Guide.
> - Groups—Displays for organizations that have Chatter enabled. If it’s not included as a distinct node in the menu, then it’s automatically
>     included in the set of Smart Search Items.
> - People—Displays for organizations that have Chatter enabled. If it’s not included as a distinct node in the menu, then it’s automatically
>     included in the set of Smart Search Items.
> - Smart Search Items—Represents a set of recently searched-for objects. Determines the content in the Recent section of the menu.
>     Only searches done in the full Salesforce site influence the objects
>     in this element, and only searchable objects display in the Recent
>     section. If users pin objects on the Search Results screen in the full
>     Salesforce site, those objects will stick to the top of the Recent
>     section.
> - Tasks—Lists of a user’s open and closed tasks, and tasks that have been delegated.
> - Today—An app that helps users plan for and manage their day, by integrating calendar events from their mobile device with their
>     Salesforce tasks, contacts, and accounts.  Available in the
>     Salesforce1 for iPhone and Salesforce1 for Android Phones downloadable
>     apps only.
> - Visualforce pages

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I don't like the smart search items that much and at first sight this would indeed seem the only way you could show your objects.

However, if you would only want to show some specific object's data and not all, you could also just use FlexiPages. (one flexipage per object for example)
In my last project, this is how I presented most of the data to the users and they realy liked it much better than the smart seach items.

FlexiPages are also real easy to create so don't be afraid of investing maybe half an our in trying it out. (it shouldn't take you much more time)

Here is the blogpost I have written about flexipages:
http://www.absi.be/article.aspx?id=1121